# Salt within for loop using incremental variable to set value in sed command

Tags: bash, sed, salt-stack

What I'm trying to do is have salt set an internal host ip based on the current value of `$i` from the for loop. I've tried the following but was unsuccessful at modifying a network script that contains this line: 192.168.200.100 which resides in all 39 nodes.

`for ((i=2; i<=30; i++)); do sudo salt -L "host$i.dev.mysite.com" cmd.run "sed -i "s/192.168.200.100/192.168.200.$i/" /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond1; done"`

Results I am looking is to have each `hostX.dev.mysite.com` bond1 files modified from 192.168.200.100 to 192.168.200.2

```
host2.dev.mysite.com /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond1 = 192.168.200.2
host3.dev.mysite.com /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond1 = 192.168.200.3
host4.dev.mysite.com /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond1 = 192.168.200.4
host5.dev.mysite.com /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond1 = 192.168.200.5
host6.dev.mysite.com /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond1 = 192.168.200.6
host7.dev.mysite.com /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond1 = 192.168.200.7
etc...
```

Comment: What is not working then?

Comment: It's just a matter of quoting. It should be: `for i in {2..30} ; do sudo salt -L "host$i.dev.mysite.com" cmd.run "sed -i 's/192.168.200.100/192.168.200.$i/' /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond1"; done`

Comment: @Inian, i am receiving the following in this link: http://dpaste.com/3XK9J2Z

Comment: @hek2mgl - with your suggestion, i am receiving something similar to the link i posted above:  http://dpaste.com/3XK9J2Z

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
for ((i=2;i<=30;i++)); do
    sudo salt -L "host${i}.dev.mysite.com" cmd.run "sed -r -i \"s@([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)[0-9]{1,3}\$@\1$i@\" /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond1"
done
```

Comment: when using zsh i get this 30x's `zsh: no matches found: sed -ri s@([0-9]1.[0-9]1.[0-9]1.)[0-9]1$@12@ /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond1.` 
when using bash, i receive this: `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: i tried your script exactly how it's written, though it's not erroring out, I am getting the same behavior similar to what I posted above. http://dpaste.com/3XK9J2Z

the sed version i am using is 4.2.2. i'm unsure on what you mean by sed being a cmd.run argument. please elaborate?